# Using ng-repeat variable inside src attribute in angularjs?

Tags: variables, angularjs, attributes, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
div.container
    script(src='/js/bootstrap/holder.js')
    p.text-info(ng-pluralize,
                count="devices.length",
                when="{ '0': 'There are no fragments.', 'one': 'There is 1 fragment.', 'other': 'There are {} fragments.'}")

    ul.unstyled(ng-repeat='fragment in devices')
        ul.thumbnails
            li.span
                div.thumbnail
                    img(src="holder.js/{{fragment.dimension.width}}x{{fragment.dimension.height}}")
                    div.caption
                        h3 {{fragment.name}}
                        p {{fragment.dimension}}
                        ul.unstyled(ng-repeat='component in fragment.components')
                            li {{ component.name }}
```

The problem is in `src="holder.js/{{fragment.dimension.width}}x{{fragment.dimension.height}}"`, i.e. even if looking at the resulting html I see a correct src (`src="holder.js/300x200"`) it does not show the image. My guess is this is not how one uses angular variables inside attributes..

How can I make it work?

EDIT:
it seems it does not execute `holder.js`.. 
here is the source: in the first call I used angular {{hash}} in the second I manually put `holder.js/300x200`

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="holder.js/1678x638">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...ElFTkSuQmCC" data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) explains that quite clearly:

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a `src` attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

So you must use:

```xml
<img ng-src="holder.js/{{fragment.dimension.width}}x{{fragment.dimension.height}}" />
```

Comment: It does not work, even if in the code I can see:

`<img ng-src="holder.js/1678x638" src="holder.js/1678x638">`

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which can reproduces the problem.

Comment: Uhmm.. without jade it seems to be working.. might it be jade conflicting with angular? http://jsfiddle.net/vXA8b/2/ (not sure how to make jade and angular work in jsfiddle)

Comment: I don't know Jade at all, but it seems to have partly the same goal as AngularJS. Why use both?

Comment: I am using jade instead of writing HTML, as a templating system. Not using the server side interpolation features of jade.

Comment: But AngularJS is also a templating system, right ? Anyway, you'd better open a new question, I personnaly can't help more on this subject.

Comment: Jade seems to conflict with angular for sure. I have the same prob.